# QSqlQuery binding values syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, qt, qt6

This code returns no records:

```
QString sql = QString("SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE dd_nomdest LIKE '%:machine';").arg(TABLE_NEW_ORDERS);

QSqlQuery query(_db);
if (!query.prepare(sql))
{
    qWarning() << ID << "Prepare query failed" << sql;
    qWarning() << ID << query.lastError();
    return false;
}

query.bindValue(":machine", machine);
qDebug() << query.boundValues();

while (query.next())
{
    // do stuff
}
```

`prepare` and `exec` return `true`.
`boundValues` return an empty list.
The `machine` variables contains the expected value.
If I compose the SQL string using the `QString` placeholder (instead of binding values) the query works as expected.

Where is the error in my syntax?

Qt 6.2.0, Ubuntu 21.10, SQL Server.

Comment: you can't use placeholders with table name or colimn names#

Comment: @nbk are you sure it applies to my code? I'm binding a column value not name

Comment: can you post the exact and colplete error message

Comment: @nbk, there are no error messages. Please read the question. All the calls returns `true`. But the query does not work as expected (i.e. it finds nothing) while creating the same query without bindings returns the expected records.

Comment: So I guess there is something wrong in my binding syntax

Answer (score 1):

You have to place the placeholder   for sql % in the bindvalue and so it replaces the whole string

```
QString sql = QString("SELECT * FROM %1 WHERE dd_nomdest LIKE :machine;").arg(TABLE_NEW_ORDERS);
...
query.bindValue(":machine", ("%" + machine))
```